# Jquery - ignore event if div has particular class?

Tags: javascript, events, jquery

Quick question - but I wondered what is the neatest way to achieve the following - 
I have this script -

```
 $('.trebBtn div').live('tap',function(event) {
   $('.trebBtn div').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');

});
```

It basically just switches states on a number of separate divs that are wrapped with the .trebBtn div.

This works well - but I dont want anything to happen when the last contained div is clicked.  This has a class of .search - is there any way that the above instructions can be ignored when clicking on this div only?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: `if ( $(this).is(".search") ) return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at jQuery's `is`. http://api.jquery.com/is/

```
$('.trebBtn div').live('tap',function(event) {
    if ( $(this).is(".search") ) return false;
    $('.trebBtn div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Another way is: using `:not` selector http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$('.trebBtn div:not(.search)').live('tap',function(event) {
    $('.trebBtn div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

or using `hasClass`: http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

```
$('.trebBtn div').live('tap',function(event) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass(".search") ) return false;
    $('.trebBtn div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: You could also use the `hasClass()` method over `is()`, which would be more optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Using **[`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** will prevent the event from ever being attached...

```
$('.trebBtn div:not(.search)').live('tap',function(event) {
    $('.trebBtn div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Or simply `$('.trebBtn div:not(.search)').live(...);` (right inside the selector)

Comment: You should use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) selector over the `not()` method as the [`live()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) state that **Chaining methods is not supported.**

Answer (score 1):

I would use `delegate` or `on` instead since `live` is deprecated.

```
$('.treBtn').delegate('div:not(.search)', 'tap', function(event) {
   alert('div clicked'); 
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuywn/1/) with a `click` event handler since i can't test it with the `tap` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.trebBtn div').live('tap',function(event) {
   if($(this).hasClass('search') == false){
     $('.trebBtn div').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
   }

})
```